# Source Insight 4.0: the word being highlighted can not seen

Tags: highlight, source-insight

In Source Insight 4.0 running on Windows 10, I came across a highlight problem.
After any word being highlighted, the word is covered with a yellow rectangle and can not be seen anymore (as shown in picture-1).

```
                                           picture-1
```

[image]

Though the word can be seen by selecting it once more (as shown in picture-2), it's unbearable to see the yellow rectangle once the word is highlighted.

```
                                           picture-2
```

[image]

Could anyone help to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have your highlight foreground color set to the same as the background color...

Go to Options->Style Properties

In the Style Name box, scroll down to your highlight entry, click on it, go to Colors / Foreground and click on Set.   Select any non-yellow color.